# Render JSON in a HTML table in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a code in react, where in I want to display the json data in HTML table. I want this to be dynamic. i.e. irrespective of the type of json data I'm using, it should render in tabular format.

Here is my code with sample data.

```
const jsArray =  [{"Model":"Mazda RX4","mpg":21,"cyl":6},{"Model":"Mazda RX4 Wag","mpg":21,"cyl":6},{"Model":"Datsun 710","mpg":22.8,"cyl":""},{"Model":"Hornet 4 Drive","mpg":21.4,"cyl":""},{"Model":"Hornet Sportabout","mpg":18.7,"cyl":8},{"Model":"Valiant","mpg":18.1,"cyl":6}];

 {jsArray.length > 0 && (
        <table>
          <thead>
            {jsArray.map((item, idx) =>
              idx === 0 ? (
                <th key={idx}>
                  {Object.values(item).forEach((val) => (
                    <td>{val}</td>
                  ))}
                </th>
              ) : (
                <tr key={idx}>
                  {Object.values(item).forEach((val) => (
                    <td>{val}</td>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              )
            )}
          </thead>
        </table>
      )}
```

When I run this code, nothing is getting rendered. When I replace `<tr key={idx}>{Object.values(item).forEach((val)=> (<td>{val}</td>))}</tr>` with `null`, In my output I see null printed in my front end. Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `jsArray` is a _string_, not an array. You can't `map` over it.

Comment: use `JSON.parse(jsArray).map()` because `jsArray` is a stinrg

Comment: My bad @Andy and @Liki. The` jsArray` I added here is sample data. In my real code, it is of type object. Updated the code in my question;

Comment: Do note that while adding `key={idx}` does get rid of the warning, it is not correct. `key` is used to detect order change; using order index defeats the purpose.

Comment: I didn't catch you @ColouredPanda. Sorry, I'm learning react and trying out different things to get an hands on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might make it easier if you broke all that logic down into more helpful functions.

1. `getHeadings` `maps` over the first object and grabs its [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/keys).
2. `getRows` `maps` over all the data, and calls `getCells` with each object's data.
3. `getCells` `maps` over the object and uses [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the information for each cell.

This way your component is a lot cleaner.

```js
// `map` over the first object in the array
// and get an array of keys and add them
// to TH elements
function getHeadings(data) {
  return Object.keys(data[0]).map(key => {
    return <th>{key}</th>;
  });
}

// `map` over the data to return
// row data, passing in each mapped object
// to `getCells`
function getRows(data) {
  return data.map(obj => {
    return <tr>{getCells(obj)}</tr>;
  });
}

// Return an array of cell data using the
// values of each object
function getCells(obj) {
  return Object.values(obj).map(value => {
    return <td>{value}</td>;
  });
}

// Simple component that gets the
// headers and then the rows
function Example({ data }) {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>{getHeadings(data)}</thead>
      <tbody>{getRows(data)}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

const data = [{"Model":"Mazda RX4","mpg":21,"cyl":6},{"Model":"Mazda RX4 Wag","mpg":21,"cyl":6},{"Model":"Datsun 710","mpg":22.8,"cyl":""},{"Model":"Hornet 4 Drive","mpg":21.4,"cyl":""},{"Model":"Hornet Sportabout","mpg":18.7,"cyl":8},{"Model":"Valiant","mpg":18.1,"cyl":6}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
table { border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; border-collapse: collapse; }
th { background-color: #efefef; text-align: left; text-transform: uppercase; }
td { border: 1px solid #efefef; }
td, th { padding: 0.4em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
  const data = JSON.parse(jsArray);
  const keys = Object.keys(data.length ? data[0] : {});
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {jsArray.length > 0 && (
        <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
              {keys.map((item, idx) => (
                <th key={idx}>{item}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {data.map((item, idx) => (
              <tr key={idx}>
                {keys.map((key, idx) => (
                  <td>{item[key]}</td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: This is the way to go, small nit tho you should remove the `idx` param in the last map (duplicate and unused declaration)